# How to check the version of OpenLDAP installed in command line?

Tags: openldap

I search many posts but do not see a good solution as simple as `ldap -v`. Many solutions I have tried but it does not work.

Comment: One means of doing so might be querying your package manager for the information (e.g. `yum info openldap`). According to [this openldap mailing list thread](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200411/msg00039.html), you can check the server version (on RedHat-likes) with `/usr/sbin/slapd -VV`, and client version with `ldapsearch -VV`. I suspect a bit more research would have gotten you to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running OpenLDAP on windows machine one can check the version number by just navigating to the OpenLDAP directory from command prompt and execute the command `slapd.exe -VV`

```
c:\OpenLDAP> slapd.exe -VV
OpenLDAP 2.4.42 Standalone LDAP Server (slapd)
```

Comment: For Linux simple use `slapd -VV`. =D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strings slapd | grep \$OpenLDAP` or `/usr/sbin/slapd -VV`.

The location of slapd may be different from your OpenLDAP installation location so you may need to modify the command shown in the second example to work with your computer.